# How to click button of prompt of webpage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

So I was building this web automation with puppeteer in node js. This automation should go to zoom enter the meeting id and click join button.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://us04web.zoom.us/join');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
  //await browser.close();
  
  await page.type("#join-confno", "123 456 7890", {delay: 100})
  await page.click("#btnSubmit")
})();
```

the script runs and after it runs, the browser opens and does the automation but this popped up that ruined my whole idea:
[image: this prompt]

and now i want the script to press "open zoom meeting"
im new to node js tho. Is there any idea how to do that?